# How to implement a proxy server?

Tags: java, proxy

I'm looking to have my application connect to the internet through a proxy server (in order to avoid captcha). The code I am currently using is this:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("http.proxyPort", proxyPort); //proxy port
props.put("http.proxyHost", proxyHost); //proxy host
props.put("http.proxySet", "true");
```

This code has been unsuccesful, however. Any suggestions?

Comment: you are trying to use a proxy not implement one right?

Comment: How can you use a proxy to avoid captcha?

Comment: You might need to set the proxy for https as well.  Set the properties `https.proxyPort` and `https.proxyHost`.  It might also help to set these properties in the JAVA_OPTS environment variable so they're picked up by every Java app on your system.

Comment: Sites like omegle.com (something my app connects to) generate a captcha depending on how many connections your IP has had in the past minute/hour/day. New IP = avoid captcha.

Comment: @JohnSmith: That looks like pretty badass idea, that is going to fail, because the proxy doesn't change IP when you connect to it. Or you should use each time another proxy, which is pretty hard.

Comment: Have you tried using `System.setProperty(String, String)` instead of your method. The setProperty method does slightly a little bit more than simply setting it.

Comment: http.proxySet is a urban myth. Setting it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress(proxy_host_name, proxy_port_address);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.xxx, sa);
URLConnection con = new URL(url).openConnection(proxy);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a kind of "User Friendly Website Proxy", like http://newipnow.com or [www.proxyultra.com](http://www.proxyultra.com). But you need to use a real [SOCKS proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS) server.

A free server, that I found, working, in a list of public Proxies:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "187.115.172.82");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8181");
```

There is no need to set the `http.proxySet` property.

Pick a server from the nice list here: [Hide My Ass: Proxy List](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-225391)

Answer (score 0):

Put the parameters on the command line or use `setProperty`.

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.host -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 MainClass
```